# richtextbox font

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to change the font color and size for 1 line in richTextBox

```
   String [] wo = {"hi","hello","11111","he","she"};
   richTextBox1.SelectionFont = new Font("Verdana", 10, FontStyle.Regular);
   richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Blue;
   richTextBox1.SelectedText += Environment.NewLine + wo[0];
   richTextBox1.SelectedText += Environment.NewLine + wo[1];              
   richTextBox1.SelectedText += Environment.NewLine + wo[2];
   richTextBox1.SelectedText += Environment.NewLine + wo[3];
   richTextBox1.SelectedText += Environment.NewLine + wo[4];
```

I want to change just the string "11111" and keep the rest lines as default
any help

Comment: And do you want to keep/restore the selection?

Comment: yes, just change wo[2] to blue and keep the rest as default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
private static void setColorOnLine(RichTextBox richTextBox1, int line, Color col) {
    // save old values
    int caretPosition = richTextBox1.SelectionStart;
    int selectionLength = richTextBox1.SelectionLength;
    Color selectionColor = richTextBox1.SelectionColor;

    int start = richTextBox1.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(line);
    int count = richTextBox1.Lines[line].Length;
    richTextBox1.Select(start, count);
    richTextBox1.SelectionColor = col;

    // restore
    richTextBox1.SelectionStart = caretPosition;
    richTextBox1.SelectionLength = selectionLength;
    richTextBox1.SelectionColor = selectionColor;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Select` method to select the row (via text positions) and then you use the properties `SelectionColor` and `SelectionFont` to change the settings.

You can use the `Find` method to find the text to change.

Here's the help page for `Select`:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc4fh98s.aspx